# Formatting API List with for loop in a Table

Tags: python, python-3.x, tabulate

I want to output a list I get from the API in a table so it looks nicer.
The data from the API is returned with a for loop. My problem now is that I don't know how to get it that the header isn't looped every time.

for Example:

And i want one header and the rest under the header

I have managed with some instructions from here that the data will be displayed with "Tabulate" at all in a table.
However, the "header" will be inserted at each run again.

`head = ["Datum", "Username", "License Server", "Feature Name", "Max. Usage", "Hours Used", "Max Used", "Hours Borrowed", "Max Borrowed"]`

````
for item in (data['data'])
   if item['un'] == tecNo:
      print(tabulate([[item['fud'], item['un'], str(item['lsn']), str(item['fns']), str(item['musage']), str(item['hu']), str(item['mu']), str(item['hb']), str(item['mb'])]],headers=head, tablefmt="grid"))```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHODf.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNci2.png
````

Comment: You should read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) because currently your question is off topic as we can't run or test it.

Comment: What package does the `tabulate` function come from?

Comment: Hey, its importet from Tabulate "from tabulate import tabulate"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the items in a 2d array, then call `tabulate` at the end.

```
table = []
for item in (data['data'])
   if item['un'] == tecNo:
      table.append([
          item['fud'], 
          item['un'], 
          str(item['lsn']), 
          str(item['fns']), 
          str(item['musage']), 
          str(item['hu']), 
          str(item['mu']), 
          str(item['hb']), 
          str(item['mb'])
      ])
tabulate(table, headers=head)
```